I Don't Want Hyphenation---But I Also Don't Want This
MWE:
\documentclass[ebook,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % To prevent hyphenation of words
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}

Output:

Without resorting to hyphenation, how may I get Latex to drop an entire word to the next line rather than enter the right-hand margin area?

Depends on whether you want a straight right edge. \sloppy vs \raggedright.

What’s the reason for rejecting hyphenation?

@egreg I'm trying to get a PDF adapted for an ebook. With the Kindle software, I have notice that often times parts of words disappear if they're too far to the right and it's not clear to me that the said software does such a great job with hyphenation.

@egreg: I rarely want hyphenation over wrap at start of word that would overflow.

Using the microtype package can help. Also, as suggested by @daleif, using something like \sloppy can help. But in fact, \sloppy is a bit too aggressive. In the memoir class one can find \midsloppy, and that suffices here. In fact, for your example any of the two cures help. Below we show the output with the latter.
\documentclass[ebook,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % To prevent hyphenation of words
\usepackage{lipsum}

% \usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand*{\midsloppy}{%
  \tolerance 5000%
  \hbadness 4000%
  \emergencystretch 1.5em%
  \hfuzz .1pt
  \vfuzz\hfuzz}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\midsloppy
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


Memoir also has an environment if you want to do this locally
\newenvironment{midsloppypar}{\par\midsloppy}{\par}

Of course, you might now come back and show an even more problematic paragraph, and then you might need rewriting or doing something else locally.

it doesn't really hurt here, but notice that the % after the numbers in your \midslopyy macro are kind of wrong, leaving a space after a number to terminate TeX's number scanning is advised (and omitting it might lead to bugs in different code).

Thanks, I should have mentioned that I just copied the definition from memoir.cls (except for the pt that there is \p@).

Thank you for this answer.
